# Java subtract LocalTime

Tags: java, localtime

I have two `LocalTime` objects:

```
LocalTime l1 = LocalTime.parse("02:53:40");
LocalTime l2 = LocalTime.parse("02:54:27");
```

How can I found different in minutes between them?

Comment: Note that all existing answers assume the times to be on the same calendar day. That is, the difference between 23:58 and 00:03 would be given as -1435 minutes, not 5 minutes as one might expect. (This is probably by design, because a LocalTime does not know about the length of the respective day)

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Use `until` or `between`, as described by the [api](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html#until-java.time.temporal.Temporal-java.time.temporal.TemporalUnit-)

```
import java.time.LocalTime;
import static java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit.MINUTES;

public class SO {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LocalTime l1 = LocalTime.parse("02:53:40");
        LocalTime l2 = LocalTime.parse("02:54:27");
        System.out.println(l1.until(l2, MINUTES));
        System.out.println(MINUTES.between(l1, l2));
    }
}
```

> 0
>   
>   0

Answer (score 47):

Since Java 8 you can use [`Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html) class. I think that gives the most elegant solution:

```
long elapsedMinutes = Duration.between(l1, l2).toMinutes();
```

Answer (score 9):

**I do this  with** [ChronoUnit](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/ChronoUnit.html#method.summary)

```
long minutesBetween = ChronoUnit.MINUTES.between(l1,l2);
```

**Example**

```
    LocalTime localTime=LocalTime.now();
    LocalTime localTimeAfter5Minutes=LocalTime.now().plusMinutes(5);
    Long minutesBetween=ChronoUnit.MINUTES.between(localTime,localTimeAfter5Minutes);
    System.out.println("Diffrence between time in munutes : "+minutesBetween);
```

**Output**

```
Diffrence between time in munutes : 5
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
long dif = Math.abs (l1.getLocalMillis () - l2.getLocalMillis ());
TimeUnit.MINUTES.convert (dif, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

Comment: I don't think we should calculate in millis any more with the new Date/Time API