# How do you find number of seconds between two local times?

Tags: java, scala, datetime, time

In Java or Scala, what is the best way to find the number of seconds between 2 `LocalTimes`?

If I have `11:20:00.000Z` and `11:21:00.500Z` I would want the result to be `61` seconds, not `60` seconds.

Comment: Isn't this just a rounding problem (from 60.5 seconds)?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28353725/java-subtract-localtime discusses how to do this for minutes.

Comment: @RStrad These solutions all round down, as do most date/time libraries I've looked at.

Comment: Why do you think it should round to 61?  60.5 should round to 60 as the nearest even.

Comment: @Joe C Because my use case requires that. For example, if I wanted the length of a flight in seconds, and I decided I wanted to round up to the nearest second.

Comment: @Thilo Yes it is a rounding problem. Almost every date/time library seems to round down instead of up.

Comment: Your times seem to be `OffsetTime`s  rather than `LocalTime`s. As long as both have the same offset, it doesn’t matter. Could they have different offsets? That would complicate things, but a solution could still be found.

Comment: What rounding do you want? Always up? And does that mean a ceiling or away from 0?

Answer (score 4):

Give a try to `LocalTime#until`

```js
LocalTime past = LocalTime.now().minusSeconds(4);
LocalTime now = LocalTime.now();

System.out.println("4 == " + past.until(now, ChronoUnit.SECONDS));
```

You can find more about the method in doc of [LocalTime#until](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalTime.html#until(java.time.temporal.Temporal,java.time.temporal.TemporalUnit)).

Answer (score 2):

You can calculate the time difference in `millis` and round the result in seconds using `math.round()`

```
import java.time.{LocalTime, OffsetTime}
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit.MILLIS

val t1 = LocalTime.parse("11:20:00.000")
val t2 = LocalTime.parse("11:21:00.500")

math.round(MILLIS.between(t1, t2) / 1000.0)
// res1: Long = 61
```

[UPDATE]

The above timezone-ignored calculation works fine given that the times to be compared are in the same timezone.  In case different timezones are involved, [OffsetTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetTime.html) as suggested in @studx's answer should be used instead:

```
val t1 = OffsetTime.parse("11:20:00.000Z")      // UTC +00:00
val t2 = OffsetTime.parse("11:21:00.500-01:00") // UTC -01:00

math.round(MILLIS.between(t1, t2) / 1000.0)
// res2: Long = 3661
```

Comment: Thanks. That is the way I had decided to do it. I didn't know if there was any more elegant way.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use `LocalTime`, but the inputs (11:20:00.000Z) have the `Z` in the end, which is the [UTC designator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Coordinated_Universal_Time_(UTC)). If the times are in UTC, it's not wise to ignore this info - assuming that other inputs may have another offsets.

So I would not ignore the `Z` and [use the proper type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetTime.html):

```
OffsetTime t1 = OffsetTime.parse("11:20:00.000Z");
OffsetTime t2 = OffsetTime.parse("11:21:00.500Z");
```

Both inputs have the same offset, so using `LocalTime` will work as well. But if there are inputs with different offsets, then `OffsetTime` is the right type to use.

Then you get the difference in milliseconds and round it to get the rounded seconds:

```
long millis = ChronoUnit.MILLIS.between(t1, t2);
long seconds = Math.round(millis / 1000.0); // 61
```

Answer (score 0):

**DateFormatter, LocalTime and Duration in java.time**

```
val time1 = "11:20:00.000Z"
val time2 = "11:21:00.500Z"

import java.time._
import java.time.format._
val format = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm:ss.SSS")
val parsedTime1 = LocalTime.parse(time1.replace("Z", ""), format)
val parsedTime2 = LocalTime.parse(time2.replace("Z", ""), format)
val diff = Duration.between(parsedTime1, parsedTime2)
val roundedSeconds = math.round((diff.getSeconds.toDouble+(diff.getNano.toDouble/1000000000.0)))
println(roundedSeconds)
//61 is printed
```

**using SimpleDateFormat in java.text**

```
val time1 = "11:20:00.000Z"
val time2 = "11:21:00.500Z"

import java.text._
val format = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss.SSSZ")
val parsedTime1 = format.parse(time1.replaceAll("Z$", "+0000"))
val parsedTime2 = format.parse(time2.replaceAll("Z$", "+0000"))
val diff = math round (parsedTime2.getTime - parsedTime1.getTime)/1000.0
println(diff)
//61 is printed
```

Comment: Please don’t teach the young ones to use the long outdated and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat`. Today we have so much better in [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). Which it seems the asker is probably already using. It is also so much nicer to work with.

Comment: Thanks @OleV.V. I am also learning myself as well. :) updated my answer :)

Comment: Nice. Thanks. With java.time you can do without the explicit formatter, just `LocalTime.parse(time1.replace("Z", ""))` (I believe). Or maybe even more elegant `OffsetTime.parse(time1).toLocalTime()` (using Java syntax).

Comment: yeah I just wanted to add extra information for other readers otherwise there wouldn't be any difference between my and Leo's answer @OleV.V.

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

```
ChronoUnit.SECONDS.between(                                                // Calculate elapsed time as a total number of seconds.
    LocalTime.parse( "11:20:00.000" ).truncatedTo( ChronoUnit.SECONDS ) ,  // Parse string as a `LocalTime` time-of-day, then lop off any fractional second.
    LocalTime.parse( "11:21:00.500" ).truncatedTo( ChronoUnit.SECONDS )    // Lop off the half-second present in this `LocalTime` object. 
)
```

> 60

## Truncate

If you want to ignore the fractional seconds, [truncate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html#truncatedTo-java.time.temporal.TemporalUnit-), just lop them off.

```
LocalTime start = LocalTime.parse( "11:20:00.000" ).truncatedTo( ChronoUnit.SECONDS ) ;
LocalTime stop = LocalTime.parse( "11:21:00.500" ).truncatedTo( ChronoUnit.SECONDS ) ;  // Lop off the extra half-second we don't care about.
```

Calculate the elapsed time as a total number of seconds using the [`ChronoUnit`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/temporal/ChronoUnit.html) enum.

```
long seconds = ChronoUnit.SECONDS.between( start , stop ) ;
```

> 60

By the way, your Question asks about `LocalTime`, which has no concept of time zone or offset-from-UTC. Yet your example times have a `Z` on the end which is short for `Zulu` and means UTC. So those examples cannot be `LocalTime` values.

If you really have date-time values in UTC, represent them as `Instant` objects rather than as `LocalTime`. And perform the same logic: truncate, and calculate with `SECONDS.between`.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).